# Why does maven throw InvocationTargetException?

Tags: java, maven, invocationtargetexception

I am running maven from the command line

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.xmlcml.svg2xml.analyzer.DocumentListAnalyzer 
   -Dexec.args=.
```

When my program throws a RuntimeException, maven does not throw this but throws a `InvocationTargetException`

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Only one primary allowed for 3 line textL
ineGroup
        at org.xmlcml.svg2xml.text.TextLineGroup.createSuscriptTextLineList(Text
LineGroup.java:181)
        at org.xmlcml.svg2xml.text.TextLineGroup.createHtml(TextLineGroup.java:2
40)
```

This does not happen when running Eclipse.

Why does this happen? (It confused me and confuses my users).

Comment: What about the RuntimeException in the stack trace?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, that's the exception I throw and that's the final reported exception in Eclipse. What confused me that I thought that MY code was somehow throwing `InvocationTargetException` . Does the fact that maven uses reflection cause any problems?

Comment: From the source code of `exec` plugin it is clear that it uses reflection to launch your main class. If anything goes wrong (your method throws an exception, for example) it gets propagated to maven main thread and wrapped in `InvocationTargetException`. Comment from @Charlee explains this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Invoking Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) told us as the following: -

> **Reflection** provides a means for invoking methods on a class. Typically, this would only be necessary if it is not possible to cast an instance of the class to the desired type in non-reflective code.
>
> **Methods** are invoked with `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()`. **The first argument** is `the object instance` on which this particular method is to be invoked. (If the method is static, the first argument should be null.) **Subsequent arguments** are the `method's parameters`.
>
> **If the underlying method throws an exception**, ***it will be wrapped by*** an `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`. The method's original exception may be retrieved using the exception chaining mechanism's `InvocationTargetException.getCause()` method.

Since the stacktrace also told us that the `exec:java` also uses the `Reflection` as well. Then the original exception is also wrapped as well. Please refer to the source code of at [org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/xref/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecJavaMojo.html#297) for further reference.

I hope this may help.